# Spark Job Server Keep getting Invalid Jar

Tags: spark-jobserver

I did the build using sbt job-server-api/packages and sbt job-server-tests/packages.
I am able to extend/unzip the jar using jar -cxf command

```
curl --data-binary /opt/hadoop/spark-jobserver/job-server-api/target/scala-2.10/job-server-api_2.10-0.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar localhost:8090/jars/test
{
  "status": "ERROR",
  "result": "Jar is not of the right format"
}


 curl --data-binary /opt/hadoop/spark-jobserver/job-server-tests/target/scala-2.10/job-server-tests_2.10-0.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar localhost:8090/jars/test
{
  "status": "ERROR",
  "result": "Jar is not of the right format"
}

sbt version
[info] Loading project definition from /opt/hadoop/spark-jobserver/project
Missing bintray credentials /root/.bintray/.credentials. Some bintray features depend on this.
Missing bintray credentials /root/.bintray/.credentials. Some bintray features depend on this.
Missing bintray credentials /root/.bintray/.credentials. Some bintray features depend on this.
Missing bintray credentials /root/.bintray/.credentials. Some bintray features depend on this.
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/opt/hadoop/spark-jobserver/)
[info] job-server-tests/*:version
[info]  0.6.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] job-server-extras/*:version
[info]  0.6.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] job-server-api/*:version
[info]  0.6.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] akka-app/*:version
[info]  0.6.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] job-server/*:version
[info]  0.6.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] root/*:version
[info]  0.6.1-SNAPSHOT
```

I am using SPARK Version 1.5.

I am able to view Manifest.
 cat MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Vendor: spark.jobserver
Implementation-Title: job-server-tests
Implementation-Version: 0.6.1-SNAPSHOT
Implementation-Vendor-Id: spark.jobserver
Specification-Vendor: spark.jobserver
Specification-Title: job-server-tests
Implementation-URL: https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver
Specification-Version: 0.6.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Can you help me here to resolve the jar format issue?

Comment: Could you provide more information about the `jar` file and how it's created?

Comment: Hi Arc676, Thank you for quick response. This is a sample project downloaded from git hub: https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver. Jar is generated as per the steps narrated in the README.md

Answer (score 14):

Put an @ before the jar file path as below:

```
curl --data-binary @/opt/hadoop/spark-jobserver/job-server-api/target/scala-2.10/job-server-api_2.10-0.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar localhost:8090/jars/test
```